# org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl was not found

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error while running the build

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/charming/mainframer/bigovlog_android/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts' line: 4

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl', version: '1.2.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.gradle.plugin:1.2.6')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

my buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("groovy")
}
dependencies{
    gradleApi()
    localGroovy()
}
```

I tried everything but still not working

Comment: Do you happen to have any proxy settings defined?

Comment: If so, in my case the issue was that I accidentally included the user / password into the `systemProp.http.proxyHost` URL instead of splitting them out into the `systemProp.http.proxyUser` and `systemProp.http.proxyPassword` properties.

Answer (score 15):

Did you check that Android Studio wasn't running in Offline Mode? Take a look at `Preferences/Build, Execution, Deployment/Gradle/Global Gradle settings` and see if Offline Work is checked.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, my company is using a proxy behind the network.

So it must be an SSL handshake fail issue.

To fix this issue, I use [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/).

Follow these steps.

1. Download KeyStore Explorer and install it on your system. (In my case Windows10 OS)
2. Run KeyStore Explorer and open the `cacerts` file, if you are using *Android Studio on Windows 10*, it's here: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio(or Preview)\jre\jre\lib\security` with password `changeit`.
3. On the toolbar, go to `Examine -> Examine SSL`, insert these values and click `OK`.

   **SSL Host:** plugins.gradle.org
   **SSL Port:** 443
4. Click the `Import` button and `OK`.
5. `Save` the file, and go to Android Studio, run `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.
6. If Android Studio is reopened, try `Sync Project with Gradle Files` again.

Please leave a comment, if you have more questions.

Comment: I had to switch off ZScaler internet security

Answer (score 1):

The same exact build file works for me. Try clean Gradle cache in both your project and home directory and check if it will work then. If it will still fail, try to update Gradle and the plugin to the latest version `id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "1.3.2"`

Comment: How to clean `Gradle cache`?

Comment: Remove .gradle folder in project directory and in your user's home directory.

Comment: This is the correct answer!! Try to find the latest version of the 'kotlin-dsl' plugin, and use it in either of (groovy or kotlin) build scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I try `gradle --info`

the log is below:

```
Evaluating project ':buildSrc' using build file '/Users/fjh1997/mirai/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts'.
I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:1083->https://plugins.gradle.org:443: The target server failed to respond
Retrying request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:1083->https://plugins.gradle.org:443
I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:1083->https://plugins.gradle.org:443: The target server failed to respond
Retrying request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:1083->https://plugins.gradle.org:443
I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {tls}->http://127.0.0.1:1083->https://plugins.gradle.org:443: The target server failed to respond
```

It seems that pass requests to proxy 127.0.0.1:1083.However what url I set proxy  in local gradle.properties file is 127.0.0.1:8118.What's wrong with that?After long time's efforts,I find it out.

Actually,there are two gradle.properties configuration files in your system , one is in your project/.gradle，another is in ～/.gradle.And the latter is the global setting for gradle.

If the  global setting has set variables for systemProp.http.proxyHost, then whatever you set in project/.gradle/gradle.properties, proxy dosen't work at all,you have to change it in the global setting.

And BTW,I find that the global setting for gradle is changed by my android studio preference.

Answer (score 0):

I was updating my gradle to **8.2**. After facing this problem I just added `gradlePluginPortal()` into my repositories. This solved the problem.